# Is this variety reduced?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I have asked this "elementary" question on Math.stackexchange, but I didn't receive any answer.

Let $M_r$ be the vector space of matrices of size $r\times r$ over $\mathbb C$. Let $X$ be a formal variable. Denote by $V_N\subset M_r[X]$ the polynomials of degree at most $N$. Finally, let $Z$ be the fiber over the identity matrix $I_r\in V_{2N}$ of the map $V_N\rightarrow V_{2N}$ given by $$A(X)\rightarrow ^tA(-X)\cdot A(X). $$

Is the subvariety $Z_1\subset Z$ of matrices of determinant $1$ reduced?

Comment: A complete intersection is not necessarily reduced, so these two questions are independent.

Comment: Here is link to the math.SE question: [Is this variety a complete intersection](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2357182).

Comment: @SándorKovács True, but a complete intersection is Cohen-Macaulay, hence S1, and reduced is S1+R0, so proving something is a complete intersection can be a useful step towards proving it is reduced.

Answer (score 3):

Let me answer my question.

In fact the fiber is smooth. To see this consider the $\dfrac{r(r-1)}{2}(2N+1)+r(N+1)$ equations that defines this fiber. If $i,j$ are the indices of the coefficients of the matrices and $d$ corresponds to the powers of $X$, then the equations can be written explicitly in the form

$$f_{ij}^d=\sum_{k=1}^r\sum_{n+m=d}(-1)^mX_{ik}^nX_{kj}^m-\delta_{ij}\delta_{d0},$$ 
where $n$ and $m$ are between $0$ and $N$. And $X_{ij}^n$ are the variables.

Using this, then one can show (after some computation) that the Jacobian matrix of these quardratic polynomials has a full rank.

So by the Jacobian criterion of smoothness, we deduce that the fiber is smooth. Hence $Z_1$ is smooth too.